# How do I delete duplicate rows from these web logs

Tags: sql, logging, apache-spark, duplicates

I am currently analyzing some Apache web logs. Some rows contain duplicates (not complete duplicates, as the datetime can be some seconds apart.) as you can see on the image below. I am mostly using SQL within Spark. I want to  keep only one.

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8NlS.png)

Comment: did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'dropDuplicates' method to remove the duplicates instead of a group by within query.

```
'weblogs_filter_bekijk = sqlContext.sql("select endpoint from basetable5 where ip_address = '91.74.184.68'").dropDuplicates'
```

This should help you.You can refer to below link for detailed explanation of this method.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `group by` command in a SQL query, for example:

```
select * from table where x = y group by x_column
```